# PHPMyAdmin not showing values of columns

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I was testing inserts on my DB (InnoDB) and when I checked phpmyadmin to see the newly inserted rows I found that some columns were empty.
But strangely, when I did a select on those, I found that the data was actually present in the DB.

[image: http://gyazo.com/4b242e7bf97a326b53e59cd4d2cd3f07]

After sorting, the values became visible:

[image]

What could be causing this odd behaviour? I've never had this problem before and strangely, it only happens on this table and for all the foreign keys in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was fixed magically next day. Probably reboot did it.